# How to print all folder names from the parent folder in google drive?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am trying to print all folder names from the parent folder in google drive

I tried so many methods but not working..

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
console.log("Drive => ", drive.drives.appdata);
drive.files.list({
    //spaces: 'drive',
    //isRoot: true,
     //pageSize: 10,
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const files = res.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
        console.log('Files:');
        files.map((file) => {
            console.log(file);
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No files found.');
    }
});
```

Above code only giving the file name of those folder but I am trying to print all parent folder names.?

I need to print `angular_files, datastructurealgo,DSA,Tools` names. These all are folders.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by parent folder names?

Comment: @DaImTo I have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code from the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#node.js) to search for folders in Google Drive. The key here is to use `q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"` as parameter of `drive.files.list`

**Sample Code:**

```
const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
console.log("Drive => ", drive.drives.appdata);
drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
    spaces: 'drive',
    pageToken: pageToken
}, (err, res) => {
    console.log(err);
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    if (res.files.length) {
      res.files.forEach(function (folder) {
        console.log('Found folder: ', folder.name, folder.id);
      });
      pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
    } else {
        console.log('No folders found.');
    }
});
```

Please note that you might need to tweak the code based on your need.